# Can wxpython and PyQt be used together in same GUI?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, pyqt

I want to use Grid from wxpython and use it in my GUI which is based on PyQt. Is it possible?

Comment: sorry for not being super helpful, but this doesn't sound like a great idea.. having to deal with interop from different gui frameworks just for a grid looks like a ridiculous complexity augmentation for very minimal functionality gain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is, **no**.  Or, if it is possible, it's certainly not easy.

Although there are many similarities in look and function between wxPython and PyQt, under the hood they are essentially different.